# assignment of read-only location of non const variable

Tags: c++

Why does the below macro fail

```
#define XML_TEST(K, V) K = V;

struct teststruct {
    teststruct() {
        TEST("x_", 10);
    }
    int x_;
};
```

This doesnt compile with the following error:

```
test.h:30: error: assignment of read-only location ‘"x_"’
#define XML_TEST(K, V) K = V;);
```

simply doing

```
teststruct() {
    x_ = 10;
}                   ^
```

works fine. Also I dont see anything being const here. Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TEST("x_", 10);
```

will process into

```
"x_" = 10;
```

which is most definitely a problem, as we're assigning to a constant string. I believe you mean

```
TEST(x_, 10);
```

Comment: ahhhh, right... that is it. thanks for highlighting. Been a bit blind here